# postgresql: data type for iterable in select statement

Tags: sql, arrays

I'm trying to create an iterable variable to use in a select statement. If I hardcode the variable, my code block works fine:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  num integer;
BEGIN
  num := (select count(*) from event where event_status in ('pending', 'failed'));
  raise notice 'count here: %', num;
END;
$$
```

However, if I try to create a variable called `statuses` out of the iterable I get an error saying 'syntax error at or near "array"':

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  statueses array := ('pending', 'failed');
  num integer;
BEGIN
  num := (select count(*) from event where event_status in statuses);
  raise notice 'count here: %', num;
END;
$$
```

Am I using the wrong datatype? How can get this to work? Note I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: See http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/07/postgresqls-findinset.html for how to create a PG equivalent to MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET()` function, then use a comma-separated string `statuses := 'pending,failed';`

Comment: Could be try `statuses text[] := '{"pending","failed"}'`. Not sure the syntax though.

Comment: @Hitobat getting an error: `syntax error at or near "statuses"`